# ionic app is working on emulator but not in phone

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created a hybrid app using ionic. When I test the login feature in the app using ionic serve then I am able to login on both IONS and android. Howver, when I build an apk and test the same login feature on the phone I am getting a login fail error.  Subsequently I installed Gapdebug and tried to debug on the phone. Gapdebug is showing me the following error :

### In the Console tab:

POST http://localhost:8100/api/v2/auth/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

### In the network tab:

1.Request URL: http://localhost:8100/api/v2/auth/login.

2.Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.

1.Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

2.Cache-Control: no-cache

3.Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

4.Origin: file://

5.Pragma: no-cache

6.User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; XT1022 Build/KXC21.5-40) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36

Please advise as to how I can fix this.
Thanks

Comment: Is your phone and the machine running the server in the same network?

Comment: You are trying to access `localhost` from your phone, you should put the local IP of the machine the server is running on instead. And make sure your phone is connected to the same wifi network as well.

Comment: the server is  running in remote host so i made one proxy in my ionic.project file i.e. 
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://remotehost.com/api"
    } 
and in app.js file I have add the constant : 
.constant('ApiEndpoint', {
  url: 'http://localhost:8100/api'
})